TextInputSwitcher prevents Finder from using Command + Shift + (.) keyboard shortcut
I've encountered a strange issue on my M1 MacBook Air running macOS 14.5 Sonoma where Finder is unable to take advantage of the Command + Shift + . shortcut to show/hide hidden files. When I use the shortcut, nothing happens in Finder when previously the shortcut worked as expected. I'm not sure exactly when this started.
I used ShortcutDetective to determine that the Command + Shift + . shortcut was being intercepted by TextInputSwitcher, and I found it running in Activity Monitor. After forcing the process to quit, the shortcut works as expected in Finder again. But once I use the langauge switcher (globe icon on my MacBook), TextInputSwitcher is relaunched and the issue re-appears.
I have checked under System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts and verified that input switching is set to use the same Command + Shift + . shortcut as Finder uses to show/hide hidden files, however my research indicates that this is expected and I have not changed that shortcut. And, like I said, the shortcut worked fine in Finder when I tried to use it before today. I've also tried all generally recommended troubleshooting steps — this issue did not occur before I updated to macOS 14.5.
Anyone else encountered this issue and identified a fix? I'm aware that I can use a Terminal command to show/hide hidden files, but that doesn't do anything to address the broken shortcut. Thanks.

Control + Space is the default for “Select the previous input source” in System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Input Sources, according to https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-mac-mchlp1406/14.0/mac/14.0. I do not recall if it has ever changed, but the High Sierra version of that page shows the same shortcut.
If change input source is still set to Command + Shift + . for you, I suggest you first click “Select the previous input source” so that it is selected and then click the “Restore Defaults” button. I have confirmed on macOS 14.6.1 as well as an older machine with macOS 12.7.6 that setting it to Command + Shift + . as you have will cause text input switching to override showing hidden files, even when in the Finder.
There is one “gotcha” here: there seems to be hidden additional shortcut where if you hold shift along with your assigned shortcut for “Select the previous input source,” it will switch in the opposite direction. So if you leave it at the default Control + Space, then Control + Shift + Space is also silently assigned. This is as a distinct action separate from the other setting, “Select next source in Input menu.” The hidden additional key combination is therefore unavailable to be assigned as shortcuts in other software.
[Incidentally, that is how I came to your question when I was trying to find out why my use of Control + Shift + Space in another program was not working, even though I could not find it assigned anywhere. Your mention of ShortcutDetective and forcing textInputSwitcher to quit was a helpful clue that eventually led me to discover that “gotcha.”]

Restoring both shortcuts for Input Sources to default did the trick! I'm not sure why I never tried to reset them, I suppose I thought they were already at their defaults because I can't remember how or why I would have changed them in the 10 years I've had a Mac. Thank you!
